# AngularJS: Using "this" in an interval function within a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

How can I get the "this" keyword working for `periodicFetch()` when it's called via `$interval`?

This is the code of my angular application:

```
angular.module('myapp', []);

var MyService = function($rootScope, $http, $interval) {
    this.variables = {};

    this.registerVariable = function(varName) {
        this.variables[varName] = null;
    };

    this.periodicFetch = function() {
        console.log(this.variables);
    };

    this.run = function() {
        this.periodicFetch();
        $interval(this.periodicFetch, 1000);
    };
};

angular.module('myapp').service('myService',
        ['$rootScope', '$http', '$interval', MyService]);

angular.module('myapp').run(function(myService) {
    myService.registerVariable('foo');
    myService.run();
});
```

Currently the output is:

```
Object {foo: null}
undefined
undefined
undefined
...
```

It seems to work for the first invocation without `$interval`. But within `$interval` the value of `this.variables` seems to be `undefined`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), like so

```
$interval(this.periodicFetch.bind(this), 1000);
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/554/)

Comment: Thank you for your concise and helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

*this* refers to the function scope. One option is to store a reference to it in variable, often named self. `var self = this;`, however using bind is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!